# Bootstrap eyeon Color Picker val Not Defined

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, color-picker

I am using eyeon color picker for selecting in my HTMl. could any one help how to use it. The following is the way I have used it.

```
<div class="well">
    <div id="cp3" data-color-format="hex" data-color="rgb(255, 146, 180)" class="input-append color">
        <input type="text" readonly="" value="" class="span3">
        <span class="add-on"><i style="background-color: rgb(255, 146, 180)"></i></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am getting JS error "**val is not defined**" in bootstrap-colorpicker.js

Comment: can you create a test page for it

Answer (score 1):

In the example that is given the js call is stated as:

```
$('.colorpicker').colorpicker();
```

Change this to:

```
 $('.color').colorpicker();
```

Comment: where is the js call given above ??? where did you find $('.colorpicker').colorpicker(); and saying it to change